# Perl sort : How to sort a out put

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

How do I sort an output like this

Current:

```
Shift : 01 
TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES ====> 15937 
# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS ====> 455 
GAP MINUTUES ====> 22158 
# OF OFFICERS ====> 28 
TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN ====> 1708 
TICKET WRITTEN ====> 19929
```

I want to sort like this:
(Info: I have initial the hash value like this, but it doesn't print in order)

```
Shift : 01 
# OF OFFICERS ====> 28 
# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS ====> 455 
TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES ====> 15937
TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN ====> 1708 
TICKET WRITTEN ====> 19929 
GAP MINUTUES ====> 22158
```

My code:

```
foreach my $k (sort keys %Shift_name) {
    print "\n\n$k \n";
    while (my ($kk, $val) = each %{ $Shift_name{$k} }) {
        print  " $kk ====> $val \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach my $kk (sort keys %{Shift_name{$k}})`

Answer (score 2):

The order of your keys appears arbitrary.

Therefore, you'll have to create a separate hash that specifies the order of keys to be used by sort.

The following demonstrates this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Load Data into hash
my %data = split /\s*====>\s*|\n/, do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Specify order of keys
my @order = (
    '# OF OFFICERS', 
    '# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS', 
    'TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES',
    'TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN', 
    'TICKET WRITTEN',
    'GAP MINUTUES',
); 
my %order = do {my $i = 0; map {$_ => ++$i} @order};

for my $key (sort {$order{$a} <=> $order{$b}} keys %data) {
    print "$key ====> $data{$key}\n";
}

__DATA__
TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES ====> 15937 
# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS ====> 455 
GAP MINUTUES ====> 22158 
# OF OFFICERS ====> 28 
TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN ====> 1708 
TICKET WRITTEN ====> 19929
```

Outputs:

```
# OF OFFICERS ====> 28 
# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS ====> 455 
TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES ====> 15937 
TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN ====> 1708 
TICKET WRITTEN ====> 19929
GAP MINUTUES ====> 22158
```

Answer (score -1):

`List::Util`'s `pair` functions are ideal when working with hashes (and they're in core as of 5.20!). If your data structure looks like this:

```
my %shift_name = (
    28    => '# OF OFFICERS',
    455   => '# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS',
    1708  => 'TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN',
    15937 => 'TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES',
    19929 => 'TICKET WRITTEN',
    22158 => 'GAP MINUTES',
);
```

You can print it out sorted by its keys like this:

```
use List::Util qw(pairmap);
print join "\n", 
    map     { "$_->[1] ====> $_->[0]" }
    sort    { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } 
    pairmap { [$a, $b] } %shift_name;
```

which is similar to a Schwartzian transform, but in this case the anonymous arrays are only being used to keep the key/value pairs together. If the hash is inverted

```
my %shift_name = (
    '# OF OFFICERS'          => 28,
    '# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS' => 455,
    ...
```

the same general idea applies, but you have to tweak the indices:

```
print join "\n", 
    map     { "$_->[0] ====> $_->[1]" }
    sort    { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } 
    pairmap { [$a, $b] } %shift_name;
```

Both output

```
# OF OFFICERS ====> 28
# OF UN-ACCOUNTED GAPS ====> 455
TOTAL # OF OT TICKETS WRITTEN ====> 1708
TOTAL # OF OT ENTRIES ====> 15937
TICKET WRITTEN ====> 19929
GAP MINUTES ====> 22158
```

(I'm assuming in your expected output, the 1708 entry being after the 15937 entry was a typo. If you do need an arbitrary order, disregard this answer and see Miller's instead.)